# Security of Ubuntu downloads

Tags: security, downloads

When I try to download Ubuntu Desktop and try to save, it shows different URLs. What is the difference between these different URLs. Which is the safest one? ( eg. releases.ubuntu.com ; ubuntu.excellmedia.net etc. ) Can I download it from anywhere? Need I care for these things? What should I care just before saving the file.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu.excellmedia.net is a mirror. In this case for India. Mirrors are mainly there to speed up downloading: downloading from a site closer to you is faster than from a site in the UK. It also lowers stress on other servers holding the Ubuntu system. And you then also download a version with the native language incorporated and other default settings for that country. So it saves downloading extra packages afterwards. And not everyone speaks English of course.

> Can I download it from anywhere?

Yes but it is a generally smart to always check the .ISO you download against the [md5hash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM). Besides that there is also the official [mirror list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors).

> Need I care for these things?

Yes. Security is something we users need to be aware off and that starts with making sure the download is a correct untainted version.

> What should I care just before saving the file?

See the 1st part of this answer: a md5hash check should be enough.

Comment: In normal case, if I download it from any of the mirror list, will I lose any of the deb or deb-src I get from Main source/server (i.e., deb & deb-src given in sources.list.save).  I mean, will they be added packages' or a filtered and added packages'?  My doubt is about the Desktop version only.

Comment: No. All mirrors are nearly instantly updated when the main server is updated. There can be -some- lag between servers. See the mirror list. It has as status of each mirror

Comment: This doubt may be silly.....but I don't know. In normal case, can I add sources easily without MAKING DISABLE or REMOVING deb or deb-src if I download it from releases.ubuntu.com? (I remember gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.  At present I have nothing to compare the two types of sources.list)

Comment: Those will be identical. And yes sources are added pretty easily (either with gedit or with "software" from dash.

Comment: Thanks, Rinzwind.....for these descriptions about Ubuntu downloads.